# Lining up outputs in Java

Tags: java, output-formatting

I am writing a blackjack program that saves user information such as hands won, hands played, and money left for the player, and their name.  The outputs should be right justified, even when they are changing.  My current code is:

```
    System.out.format("%s \t \t \t %s %n", "Name:", playerName);
    System.out.format("%s \t \t %d %n", "Hands Played:", playerHands);
    System.out.format("%s \t \t %d %n", "Hands Won:", playerWins);
    System.out.format("%s \t \t \t %.2f %n", "Money:", playerMoney);
```

This left justifies them in the middle of the screen, but I've run out of ideas for what else to do.

Additional question: why do the 2nd and 3rd print statement only require 2 "\t"s? I assume it has something to do with the length of the strings before them, but is there a hard and fast rule for that?

Comment: It's not possible to know the width of a console, so you'll be limiting to making a solution for one particular width.

Comment: 1. That %s string you print at the beginning might push you past a tab boundary.  2. If your "console" supports variable width font (any modern GUI) then that will mess you up too.

Answer (score 4):

This should help:

```
System.out.format("%15s  %-15s %n", "Name:", playerName);
System.out.format("%15s  %-15d %n", "Hands Played:", playerHands);
System.out.format("%15s  %-15d %n", "Hands Won:", playerWins);
System.out.format("%15s  %-15.2f %n", "Money:", playerMoney);
```

Output:

```
          Name:  Player 1        
  Hands Played:  10              
     Hands Won:  2               
         Money:  15.05
```

Comment: This solved my problem for the right justifying, but now adds the problem that name, hands played, hands won, and money are now not left justified, sorry I should have been more clear.

Comment: Never mind, I  think I got it.  If I do "%15-s", should that solve my problem?  I tried it and it seems to work.